# How can we avoid folders auto-creation?

Tags: external-sd, boot, file-system

**There's a way to manage these system folders?**

I am struggling with some folders that are automatically created at boot, by system on the SD card, but I don't want them!

The folders are especially the following: LazyList, LOST.DIR

Into the latter I have found several, also big, files, and I don't want to waste the storage, maybe, with duplicated or deleted files.
There's a way to better manage, or even better, completely avoid it?

**Thank you... as always!**

Comment: `LOST.DIR` is created by FAT family of filesystems when filesystem check performs a recovery. LazyList might be created by some apps for image caching. Both cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EUREKA! I have found a way!**

After some deep "Guru meditations" I have had a "flash of a genius"... and found the way!

It relates to the file system itself.
The rule is that where it is a file with a given name in a folder, there cannot coexist a folder with the same name, so, if you, after the deletion of the folder, create a file with the same name, that folder cannot be created anymore!

.

#### So, if you want to get rid of an auto creating folder, just create a file,

#### and if you want to get rid of an auto creating file, just create a folder,

#### with the same name, in the same path.

.

The file or folder will substitute one the other, and voilà, you could avoid the creation of the almost useless folders, even included LazyList and LOST.DIR, and whatever else you want!

Man vs Filesystem: 1-0

Comment: It's good that it worked for you. But the entity creating the file/folder may simply run `rm -rf` before creating the new one, unless you make the file/folder immutable some way.

Comment: It is possible, but why to literally format a card using that command and deleting Everything, since it happens in the root directory?

Comment: I meant `rm -rf LOST.DIR` or `rm -rf LazyList`, not deleting everything. I thought that's understood. And I'm not talking about a person deleting those directories. The app or the fileaystem driver which is creating a directory (by calling [mkdir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)) can also simply delete that file (by calling [unlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)) before creating the new one, unless the file is made [immutable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206595/262728).

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, sir. I'm a newbie here, accept my apologies.
Please help me to better understand: if that entity calls, in order: chattr -i name --- rm -rf name --- mkdir name, we have lost our battle for sure? Thanks!

Comment: No need to apologize, everyone is learning here. No. The correct statement is: "if that entity calls, in order: rm -rf name; mkdir name, we have lost our battle for sure". If we have set immutable flag by running `chattr +i name`, then `rm -rf name` won't succeed. Instead `chattr -i name; rm -rf name; mkdir name` would be required to create new file/directory.

Comment: Giuseppe Uranya Di Terlizzi ᎓ I'm a bit surprised that the solution you proposed satisfies your needs, because in the end it pretty much amounts to the same thing, in the sense that you still have the same number of undesirable entries in your root folder (regardless of whether they're files or folders). A lot of people don't carecare (or even **know**, lol ⁠— lots don't) exactly what's in their root folder